# NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/util/Length, How should i fix it

Tags: spring, ubuntu-12.04, java

Hi i just recenetly updated my ubuntu 12.04 and everything was working fine. After updates when i run the project, i am getting this error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/util/Length
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-7-jdk
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

but it didn't work.

Java -version gives :

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.4) (6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Full stack trace is :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/util/Length
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:949)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.cuppla.teammatch.web.filters.OrganisationFilter.doFilter(OrganisationFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/util/Length
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11ECKeyFactory.generatePublic(P11ECKeyFactory.java:228)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11ECKeyFactory.implTranslatePublicKey(P11ECKeyFactory.java:103)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11ECKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(P11ECKeyFactory.java:152)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:321)
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.buildX509Key(X509Key.java:223)
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.parse(X509Key.java:170)
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateX509Key.<init>(CertificateX509Key.java:75)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:705)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:169)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1751)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:196)
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:107)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:322)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:763)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1201)
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:221)
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:247)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.engineInit(SSLContextImpl.java:74)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.init(SSLContext.java:265)
    at com.paypal.core.SSLUtil.getDefaultSSLContext(SSLUtil.java:52)
    at com.paypal.core.DefaultHttpConnection.setupClientSSL(DefaultHttpConnection.java:32)
    at com.paypal.core.AuthenticationService.getPayPalHeaders(AuthenticationService.java:62)
    at com.paypal.core.APIService.makeRequest(APIService.java:111)
    at com.paypal.core.BaseService.call(BaseService.java:149)
    at urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.doDirectPayment(PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.java:1559)
    at urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.doDirectPayment(PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.java:1589)
    at com.cuppla.teammatch.controllers.PaymentController.doPayment(PaymentController.java:150)
    at com.cuppla.teammatch.controllers.PaymentController.makePayment(PaymentController.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.util.Length
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 104 more
```

I am using Springtoolsuit 3.1.0
tomcat 7

kindly help me in this regard,
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389533

Comment: @Edc: i tried it but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change java version from 1.6 to 1.7. You could do this using below command which will display your installed java versions.

```
/usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```

After that choose your java version choice.

Comment: i changed it to 1.7 but not working, does it has some thing to do with sun jdk or open jdk?

Comment: java -version gives: java version "1.7.0_09"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.3) (7u9-2.3.3-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: I think you have to make sure same version is used when you run your application via spring source tool with tomcat 7

Comment: I Fixed it by uninstalling openJDK and installing Oracle java.